# One call at time by user .NET ASP .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have code which must wait before complte previous call by user.

```cs
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1, 1, "LOCK_" + UNIQUE_USER ID);
sem.WaitOne();
try
{
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
}
finally
{
    sem.Release();
}
```

But some time all stop on **sem.WaitOne();**

Where I mistake?

P.S. IIS hang too, IIS service not stops, only kill

Comment: what's returning by `sem.WaitOne();` ?

Comment: @LolCoder아카쉬 VS debuger stop on sem.WaitOne()